# Pizza, Pizza, Deep Dish Pizza!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

[April 5th](http://www.nationaldaycalendar.com/national-deep-dish-pizza-day-april-5/) is National Deep DIsh Pizza Day, the theme of this challenge. Given a positive integer `n` (`n` is greater than 0), create an ASCII deep dish pizza. Actual deep dish pizza shown:

[image: A Pizza!]

As you can see, there is a layer of crust on the bottom and surrounding the rest of the pizza.

**How to make the pizza**

The crust is made of two layers. The first layer will be `n` tall and `n*3` long. Length is the number of characters (including spaces) in the highest line. So given `n` is 1, the first layer would look like this:

```
\_/  1 character tall
 3 characters long
```

If `n` is two:

```
\    /   2 characters tall
 \__/
  6 characters long
```

Now for the second layer of the crust. It will go *outside* the first, inner crust so therefore, it will be `n+2` characters tall and `(n*3)+6)` characters long. Given `n` is one:

```
\       /  3 characters tall
 \     /
  \___/
   9 characters long (3 underscores, 3 slashes on either side)
```

If `n` is two:

```
\          / 4 characters high
 \        /
  \      /
   \____/
    12 characters long
```

You would then match up the two highest pairs of `\/` with each other for the inner and outer crust. In `n` is 1:

```
\ \   / /
 \ \_/ /
  \___/
```

If done correctly, it would look like a V without the tops with a one character difference between each layer. Speaking of tops, the crust will be joined together by a pair of `/\`, separated by a line of underscores `(n*3)+2` long to complete the crust and pizza.

**Examples**

If `n` is 1:

```
/\_____/\
\ \   / /
 \ \_/ /
  \___/
```

`n` is 2:

```
/\________/\
\ \      / /
 \ \    / /
  \ \__/ /
   \____/
```

`n` is 3:

```
/\___________/\
\ \         / /
 \ \       / /
  \ \     / /
   \ \___/ /
    \_____/
```

**Winning Criterion**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Something looks off in the inner crust examples. The one for n=1 seems to small, the one for n=2 looks like the inner crust from the final n=1 example, etc...

Comment: Can we use a `-` instead of a `_`?

Comment: @Okx No you may not

Comment: Happy Deep Dish Pizza Day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
Ｎθ←_←×_θ↖θ↖²Ｍ→/Ｐ×_⁺²×²θ↘θ↘¹\×_θ‖ＢＯθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBCoJAEIbvPYV4WsGI9mi36BJkidRNCJMxF0Zd11mjp9/UqDW7fv/wfzOTFanK6hSN2VdS01GXN1Cs8TaLSImKWHCAnHzHvbpzdBYltKwPfKfxbHiR77j5R7xHYd0BC2JxL@g74K6G8lAjCTmCSXWEumX8Y@Oja2Lb1Y9qLPsRTujaWpLE3jBfPoYcIaOtJgKV4/PUgcJUDo8whptlhy8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the size of the pizza.

```
←_←×_θ
```

Print part of the outer crust base.

```
↖θ↖²
```

Print the outer crust left side.

```
Ｍ→/Ｐ×_⁺²×²θ
```

Print part of the top crust.

```
↘θ↘¹\
```

Print the inner crust left side.

```
×_θ
```

Print part of the inner crust base.

```
‖ＢＯθ
```

Reflect to complete the pizza.

Note that modern additions to Charcoal shrink the size down to 31 bytes:

```
Ｎθ←×_⊕θ↖θ↖²Ｍ→/Ｐ×_⊗⊕θ↘⊕θ\×_θ‖ＢＯθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BCoJAEIbvPYXsaQUj8Gi38CJkhdRNCN3GXFh3123W6Ok3NVDJ4/zz8f0zrC4MU4VwLpHa4sk2JRja@vvNxXCJNDpChYF35Q28KLmTwEskM9CARHj0nD@TN/1j23UU9lGqOqBRxp81TgDZkWFjBXI9BoueWNlS9B3/fbM9Vm85@lZHTf48J9OwcI9IBpUAhgeLCKYSn3MHRhR6eN650G078QU) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Not sure if I accidentally introduced a bug, but the filling appears not to work properly?

Comment: @ASCII-only Filling? The test case at least looks right to me; what do you think isn't working?

Comment: I think it doesn't work with inputs of 4 and up?

Comment: @ASCII-only Huh, how did I overlook that...

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 136 bytes

```js
f=
n=>"/\\"+(r=s=>s[0][0].repeat(n-1)+s)`_`+r`_`+r`___/\\
`+r` `.replace(/ /g,"$`\\ \\$`   $'$'$'/ /\n")+r` \\ \\`+r`_/ /
`+r`  \\`+r`___/`
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

The whole pizza is very repetitious so the `r` function (designed as a tagged template literal) repeats the first character of its input `n` times. This handles the top and bottom two lines of the pizza. The middle is repeated by replacing a string of blanks; the `` $` `` and `$'` subsitutions automatically correspond to increasing and decreasing numbers of blanks thus positioning the `\ \` and `/ /` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 205 bytes

---

This is my first [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) post!

Add a `f=` at the beginning and invoke like `f(arg)`.

```
n=>{a=[];w=" ";u="_";t=`/\\${u.repeat(n*3+2)}/\\
`;for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){c=i==n?u:w;a.push(`${w.repeat(i)}\\ \\${c.repeat((n+1-i*2)+n+(n-1))}/ /
`)};return [t,...a,`${w.repeat(i)}\\${u.repeat(n+2)}/`].join``}
```

**Note:** *All line breaks are necessary!*

---

```js
f=n=>{a=[];w=" ";u="_";t=`/\\${u.repeat(n*3+2)}/\\
`;for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){c=i==n?u:w;a.push(`${w.repeat(i)}\\ \\${c.repeat((n+1-i*2)+n+(n-1))}/ /
`)};return [t,...a,`${w.repeat(i)}\\${u.repeat(n+2)}/`].join``}

document.querySelector("#elem").innerHTML = f(+prompt("Enter a Number"));
```

```html
<pre id="elem">
```

---

### Explanation

The code first declares an Array `a`. It then declares `w` and `u` having the value of whitespace and underscore respectively. Then, it declares a String variable to hold the value of the crust (which can be computed by `/\+(n*3+2 underscores)+/\`, as mentioned in the Challenge). After that, with a `for` loop and a `Template Literal`, the middle of the pizza is created (with each layer having `i` whitespaces at the starting and `(n+1-i*2)+n+(n-1)` whitespaces between `\ \` and `/ /`, where `i` represents the index of `for` loop). At the last, the bottom most part of the pizza is created (`(i whitespaces)+\+(n+2 underscores)+/`). All parts are joined together and output(ted).

---

If for some reason the snippet does not display the ASCII art correctly, have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MangaCoder/Loe9r1zb/).

Happy Deep Dish Pizza Day to everyone!

---

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <s>153</s> 151 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RYyxCsMwDER3f4XJcolFcNt0C/oTg0hKBi0ilBT6945dU6JFune6y8Zq@@foB7cwPIK5lSF172@1AzElEdAaJqo3nPLNbd/t1TW/RJSQfCoDqrKfgo2PoEMJ@IhZie9z9y/0S/sulc2/cKHywxKR8/ME)

```
n=input()
a=' '*n
b='_'*n
print'/\\__'+b*3+'/\\'
i=0
exec"print' '*i+'\ \\\\'+' '*(3*n-2*i)+'/ /';i+=1;"*n
print a+'\ \\'+b+'/ /'
print a+' \\_'+b+'_/'
```

-2 bytes by substituting repeated values with variables thanks to @KoishoreRoy

Comment: Instead of `print' '*=~n+'\\'+'_'*-~n+'_/'` can you not write `print' '*i+' \\_'+'_'*n+'_/'`? (Or `n` instead of `i`, but I was copying the previous line.)

Comment: @Neil I can't change `-~n` to `i`,  because at this point `i==n`. But second change is good. Also I shortended `-~n`, thanks to your idea

Comment: I wasn't simply changing `-~n` to `i`, because I was adding the space. (But you seem to have worked that out on your own anyway. Also I already noted that `n` and `i` are the same at this point.)

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB, 333 bytes

(Lazy-ish attempt)

```
function t(n);p=@(q)fprintf(q);s=@(x)p(' ');r=@()p('/ /');l=@()p('\\ \\');f=@()p('/');b=@()p('\\');u=@(x)p('_');h=@()p('/\\');e=@()p('\n');h();arrayfun(u,1:3*n+2);h();e();for i=1:n;arrayfun(s,1:i-1);l();arrayfun(s,1:3*n-2*(i-1));r();e();end;arrayfun(s,1:n);l();arrayfun(u,1:n);r();e();arrayfun(s,1:n+1);b();arrayfun(u,1:n+2);f();e();
```

#### Formatted:

```
function d(n)
p=@(q)fprintf(q);
s=@(x)p(' ');
r=@()p('/ /');
l=@()p('\\ \\');
f=@()p('/');
b=@()p('\\');
u=@(x)p('_');
h=@()p('/\\');
e=@()p('\n');
h();arrayfun(u,1:3*n+2);h();e();
for i=1:n
arrayfun(s,1:i-1); l(); arrayfun(s,1:3*n-2*(i-1)); r();e();
end
arrayfun(s,1:n); l(); arrayfun(u,1:n); r();e();
arrayfun(s,1:n+1); b(); arrayfun(u,1:n+2); f();e();
```

Basic idea is I have function handles to print everything, and then I just pretty much brute-force it. The one for loop is for the `n` layers between the very top and the bottom of the inside layer. The repetition of  (spaces) and `_` is done using `arrayfun`, with array inputs.
Will try to think of more interesting ways to do this if I get more time later.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#ZZBRC4IwFIX/yt7cNBGNXhxCP2QQWo4GcdXpoH69naWrrIfBPfd8997DZu3oPJmO2MRJyL468kHo3hqaNCo5onEXPY9YJKSF8HXGMqjbqpRiSkHr4KJu3h6ECztOENdAvaw2cOQtLmRtbf1AJu52ebmPKSmWfounO8tMlZf0oUZQJs0R5nt2XGbTIubeRPB1Q0uXLUU/k27pBX7LJrjT/NE@oV752R/ATx7E/AQ) (in Octave)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
Ａ⁺Ｎ²β↖Ｍ↓↙¹Ｍ→↘βＭ↑×_β↗βＭ←↖¹Ｍ↓↙βＭ↑←×_⁺β±²↖βＭ↘Ｍ→×_⁺×β³±⁴
```

Explanation:

```
Ａ⁺Ｎ²β       Assign input + 2 to the variable β
↖             Move up and left one, printing a \
Ｍ↓           Move pointer down one
↙¹            Move down and left one, printing a /
Ｍ→           Move pointer right one
↘β            Move down and right β times
Ｍ↑           Move pointer up
×_β           Write underscores β times
↗β            Move up and right β times
Ｍ←           Move pointer right one
↖¹           Move up and left one
Ｍ↓           Move pointer down one
↙β           Move down and right β times
Ｍ↑           Move up one
←             Set direction to left
×_⁺β±²        Write underscores β - 2 times
↖β            Move up and left β times
Ｍ↘           Move down and right one
Ｍ→           Move right one
×_⁺×β³±⁴      Write underscores (β * 3) - 4 times
```

My previous answer was in Retina, a language I haven't posted an answer to before. Now, you have an answer in Charcoal, which I haven't posted an answer to before.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z8JHjbve71l3aNO5TY/apr3fs/ZR2@RHbTMP7QQzJz1qm3FuE5g58fD0eJCa6VD@BKByqCqQBpgqoARQIdDQc5sObTwEMhMqMwNiIETyMNCUQ5sPbXzUuOX/fyMA)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>209 200 137</s> 135 bytes

finally beating JS :)

```php
echo($f=str_pad)("/\\",1+3*$x=$n=1+$argn,_),"/\\
";for(;$n;)echo$f("\\ \\",2*$n+$x," _"[!--$n]),"/ /
",$p.=" ";echo$f("\\",2+$x,_),"/";
```

Takes input from STDIN; run with `-nR` or [order a family pizza](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46dda86004c64ff7e68cd974fd2a03c4e43925cd).

**breakdown**

```php
// print top
echo($f=str_pad)("/\\",1+3*$x=$n=1+$argn,_),"/\\\n";
// loop N+1 times
for(;$n;)
    // print current line and left padding for next line
    echo$f("\\ \\",2*$n+$x," _"[!--$n]),"/ /\n",$p.=" ";
// print bottom
echo$f("\\",2+$x,_),"/";
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 200 bytes

```
@set l=@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call 
@set t=
@set s=
%l%set s=___%%s%%
@echo /\_%s%_/\
%l%echo %%t%%\ \%%s:_= %%/ /&call set t= %%t%%&call set s=%%s:~2%%
@echo %t%\ \%s%/ /
@echo %t% \_%s%_/
```

`t` contains the left indent while `s` contains the inside; its `_`s are subsituted with spaces on the middle rows. `l` just exists to avoid some repetition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 59 bytes

```
k/₴3*⇧\_*k/+,›(n`\ \\`꘍₴nεd+n⁰=` _`$i*₴`/ /`,)›\\꘍₴⇧\_*\/+,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%2F%E2%82%B43*%E2%87%A7%5C_*k%2F%2B%2C%E2%80%BA%28n%60%5C%20%5C%5C%60%EA%98%8D%E2%82%B4n%CE%B5d%2Bn%E2%81%B0%3D%60%20_%60%24i*%E2%82%B4%60%2F%20%2F%60%2C%29%E2%80%BA%5C%5C%EA%98%8D%E2%82%B4%E2%87%A7%5C_*%5C%2F%2B%2C&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 57 bytes

```
i\ \´ / /ÙãxX2r_>>Ù>>lxxE2r_À­ñHãyêP>GÄXã2é ñHÄÒ_R/\$h.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@58ZoxBzaIuCvoK@9OGZhxdXRBgVxdvZHZ5pZ5dTUeEK5BxuOLT28EaPw4srD68KsHM/3BJxeLHR4ZUKILGWw5Pig/RjpFUy9P7//28EAA)

Since, (as usual) this contains lots of nasty non-ASCII characters and unprintables, here is a hexdump:

```
00000000: 695c 205c b420 2f20 2f1b d9e3 7858 3272  i\ \. / /...xX2r
00000010: 5f3e 3ed9 3e3e 6c78 7845 3272 5fc0 adf1  _>>.>>lxxE2r_...
00000020: 48e3 79ea 503e 47c4 58e3 32e9 20f1 48c4  H.y.P>G.X.2. .H.
00000030: d25f 522f 5c1b 2468 2e                   ._R/\.$h.
```

I'll post a more detailed explanation soon, but here is a high level overview:

```
i\ \´ / /ÙãxX2r_>>Ù>>lxxE2r_
"Create 
"\ \    / /
" \ \__/ /
"  \____/
"This can probably be compressed a lot more

À­ñHãyêP>GÄXã2é ñ
"*arg1 times*, expand the pizza slice

HÄÒ_R/\$h.
"Add the crust
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>211</s> 215 bytes

```c
i,l;f(n){l=n*3+6;char u[l];for(i=0;i<l;)u[i++]='_';u[l-1]=i=0;printf("/\\%.*s/\\\n",l-4,u);for(;i<n;i++)printf("%*s\\ \\%*.s/ /\n",i,"",n*3-(2*i),"");printf("%*.s\\ \\%.*s/ /\n%*.s\\%.*s/\n",i,"",n,u,i+1,"",n+2,u);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#RY/PboMwDMbvfQoLCTX/gNGtu7h5hWn3Bk0IldVSllYwdmjFY@/MHFo6H5LP8e@L7YmMx1YEefU2qGf9is2x7mDY@wrbUyfIPiHtPMphT1pXdv2xRi5mZWVj6dxR@G5FUjiX5qrny4XE@OzFDHL2szkgO@VCpqp3DhhXeV9AEXEySWK4eSY2iiQnEv/p/I7H3yN@e7k1e3jNYEiXs9Sb2Hqc2A9fNQURRd19NgbiZkqx/pFwXQFHrBHOkocF3rZEoJ3d8skz36kYy0CWA97pcqnhzaYEMZ/nkPhgW7Fk42qcfsMpa@rmePgD)

### Pretty Code:

```c
i,l;
f(n) {
    l = n*3+6;
    char u[l];

    // Initialize u[] with a full line of underscores,
    for (i=0;i<l;)
        u[i++] = '_';

    // Make sure the string ends in a valid way
    u[l] = i = 0;

    /* Print the crust 'top'
     * l-4 dashes are needed because '/\/\'
     * %.*s notation to pad (l-4) bytes of the underscore string
     */
    printf("/\\%.*s/\\\n", l-4,u);

    /* Print n rows of just 'walls' \ \  / /
     * each row has i=0++ leading spaces,
     * and each row has n*3-(2i) center spaces
     */
    for(; i<n; i++)
        printf("%*s\\ \\%*.s/ /\n", i,"", n*3-(2*i), "");

    /* Print i spaces, '\ \', n underlines, '/ /'
     * then i+1 spaces, '\', n+2 underlines, and '/'
     */
    printf("%*.s\\ \\%.*s/ /\n%*.s\\%.*s/\n",i,"",n,u,i+1,"",n+2,u);
}
```

### Edits:

- removed s[l] and associated by switching from %.*s notation to %*.s
- added function wrapper for compliance & try it online

Comment: [197 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY/LboMwEEX3@YopEpIfAyiNWFSOf6Hqvs7CQiEZybgRhCwS8e10TEo6C/te@8yrKZrg42meCYNpRZSP5ux7GL@DjWqn64NhebBk37pjNxyvYsSPGoM07U8vLj3Fayuyyrm8VANfLmYYih2O0tA@GrkSuRqcA8ZUOVRQJYwwy5B7FFSQ1myk@afLPzxVTfjz5dnklYsjkt4uUr@nltPM@dB5iiIJ358ahLSPUqxvEh4b4Eh/ZBbJW4AguzVAe1vzqfVKpVgHshzwRfe7h0@bEyS/zCHNi23F6qbNNP8C "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 74 Bytes

*Way* too long. I'm going to try another approach.

```
"/\\"ri:M3*:A2+'_*1$NL{"\ \\"AS*"/ /"3$S+A((:A;N\}M*4$A'_*4$N4$S'\A2+'_*'/
```

Builds the string line-by line. Nothing too crazy.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 89 bytes

Well, this is actually longer than my other solution at the moment, but I think it's more golfable:

```
ri{:T)_S*a*ee_{~'\t}%TS*aTU+*'_f+@{~'/t}%W%++z}:K~2S*f{\+}T1:U+K..e>"/\\"'_T3*(*1$++a\+N*
```

Stack trace:

```
"2" ; r
2 ; i
2 {:T)_S*a*ee_{~'\t}%TS*aTU+*'_f+@{~'/t}%W%++z} ; {}
2 {:T)_S*a*ee_{~'\t}%TS*aTU+*'_f+@{~'/t}%W%++z} ; :K
2 ; ~
2 ; :T
3 ; )
3 3 ; _
3 3 " " ; S
3 "   " ; *
3 ["   "] ; a
["   " "   " "   "] *
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ; ee
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] [[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ; _
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ; {~'\t}%
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] 2 ; T
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] 2 " " ; S
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] "  " ; *
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  "] ; a
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  "] 2 ; T
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  "] 2 0 ; U
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  "] 2 ; +
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  " "  "] ; *
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  " "  "] '_ ; '_
[[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  _" "  _"] ; f+
["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  _" "  _"] [[0 "   "] [1 "   "] [2 "   "]] ; @
["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  _" "  _"] ["/  " " / " "  /"] ; {~'/t}%
["\  " " \ " "  \\"] ["  _" "  _"] ["  /" " / " "/  "] ; W%
["\  " " \ " "  \\" "  _" "  _" "  /" " / " "/  "] ; ++
["\      /" " \    / " "  \__/  "] ; z
["\      /" " \    / " "  \__/  "] "  " ; 2S*
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] ; f{\+}
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] 2 ; T
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] 2 1 ; 1
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] 2 1 ; :U
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] 3 ; +
["  \      /" "   \    / " "    \__/  "] ["\          /" " \        / " "  \      /  " "   \____/   "] ; K
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] ; ..e>
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" ; "/\\"
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" '_ ; '_
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" '_ 3 ; T
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" '_ 9 ; 3*
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" '_ 8 ; (
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" "________" ; *
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\\" "________" "/\\" ; 1$
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] "/\________/\\" ; ++
["\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] ["/\________/\\"] ; a
["/\________/\\" "\ \      / /" " \ \    / / " "  \ \__/ /  " "   \____/   "] ; \+
"/\________/\
\ \      / /
 \ \    / / 
  \ \__/ /  
   \____/   " ; N*
; [implicit output]
```